# Bootstrap Popup is not working for me

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new in bootstrap.I have no idea how to add a bootstrap pop up in a html page. Please help me how to add  bootstap pop up in a html page

Comment: You need to do some research, try something and then ask about specific problems you're having, this question is too broad

Comment: What do you mean by 'add bootstap pop up in a html page'? What I understand is you need this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Can we see, whatever you have tried/coded until now? Have you tried the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo (parts, taken from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)) (You can copy paste it):

```
    <html>
    <head>
         <!-- jQuery is required -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

         <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
               <!-- Trigger Button for Modal -->
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
           Click To Show Modal
        </button>


        <!--Your Modal Body Here -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <!--Your Modal Close Button-->
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <!--Your Modal Title-->
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please Login</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!--Your Modal content here-->
                  Username: <input type="text" class="form-control"></input>
                  Password: <input type="password" class="form-control"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Checkout this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gezru4m0/

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have declared all the javascripts and css in your page:
you can visit these links,
http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/